# Appending a table inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following loop which is giving me problems

```
$("#divResults").append('<table>');

$.each( results.d, function( index, record ) {
    $("#divResults").append('<tr><td>' + record.ClientCode + '</td></tr>');
});

$("#divResults").append('</table>');
```

For some reason based on google chromes developer tools, the above code produces the following html

```
<table></table>
<tr><td>Code 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Code 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Code 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Code 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Code 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Code 6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Code 7</td></tr>
```

How can this be fixed to produce correct HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery operates on **elements** not tags.

You can't append a start tag, then some content, then an end tag.

```
var html = '<table>';
$.each( results.d, function( index, record ) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + record.ClientCode + '</td></tr>';
});
html += '</table>';
$("#divResults").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $("<table></table>");

$.each( results.d, function( index, record ) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    var cell = $("<td></td>").text(record.ClientCode).appendTo(row);
    table.append(row);
});
$("#divResults").append(table);
```

Comment: the above code will yield the same output as in the question.There will not be any closing </table> tag.

Comment: @tito — No, it won't. It creates a table element and then appends a bunch of table rows to it. The code in the question created a table element, appended it to a div, and then appended a series of table rows to the **div**.

Comment: @tito u'r wrong in that code i create table element and past child elements to that table element.

Comment: @quentin , I was referring to the answer by @ yorgo

Answer (score 0):

> you can also do this by dom : `document.getElementById('divResults).innerHTML= "<table><tr><td>Hi ! I am new table</td></tr></table>"`